# Sticky footer in HTML/CSS, display issues

Tags: css, html, footer, sticky

I am working on a website and have tried to stick the footer to the bottom, since many pages will not be long enough to push the footer to the bottom.

I have applied this technique: http://mystrd.at/modern-clean-css-sticky-footer/

My page can be viewed here: https://jsfiddle.net/cgLf0oLa/

I believe that this CSS input is very important:

```
html    {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
}
body    {
    margin: 0 0 400px;
}
```

However, I am experiencing trouble. The footer is being rendered on top of the other content, and I have no clue how to make it adjust to the content size.
Help is much appreciated.

Kind regards,

Clemens

Comment: I am seeing the #footer at the bottom in the fiddle link with Chrome, Edge and Mozilla, which browser is giving you problems?

Comment: @spaniard if you resize the browser to a lower height, is is wrong. Position absolute tells so put the element out of the usual object-flow and it sets upon the other content.

Comment: @callmeniko I had resized the browser to minimum sizes, the footer still at the bottom...

Comment: @spaniard if I understood it right, he tries to make a STICKY footer, if it has position absolute it CAN NOT BE STICKY, you know what i mean?

Comment: No I don't know, he wants the footer always at the bottom that is different to sticky.

Comment: I suggest you to use flexboxes to make the footer sticky https://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/sticky-footer/

Comment: Thank you!! Using the flexbox method has worked! :) It required some tweaking, but it works perfectly now! :D

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an `:after` with height equal the height of the footer to the wrapper above the footer. It leaves blank area below the footer, which pushes the footer to the bottom.